# View protocol - any vs. some vs AnyView vs. generics

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationview, swiftui-navigationstack, viewbuilder

I'm looking to create a protocol upon `View` to group views that can be constructed from some specific data struct (`MyData`)

```swift
protocol EncodableView: View {
  /// Returns true if this view type can be decoded from data
  static func canDecode(from data: MyData) -> Bool

  /// Constructs a view from the given data
  init(from data: MyData) throws
}
```

I want to use this protocol in a view to route to different views based on their ability to *decode* `MyData`:

```swift
struct Example: EncodableView {
  // ... implements EncodableView
}

struct ContentView: View {
  private var encodableViews: [any EncodableView.Type] = [ 
    ExampleView.self,
    // ... others
  ]

  private func navigationDestination(for data: MyData) -> some View {
    for (type in encodableViews) {
      // Compile complains: Type 'any EncodableView' cannot conform to 'View'
      if (type.canDecode(data)) { 
        return type.init(from: data)
      }
    }

    return EmptyView()
  }

  var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
      VStack {
        // ...
      }
      .navigationDestination(for: MyData.self) { data in
         navigationDestination(for: data)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, I'm having trouble finding the right combination of `some View`, `any View`, `AnyView` and generics to achieve this.

I've marked the spot in my code snippet above where the compile complains: `Type 'any EncodableView' cannot conform to 'View'`

Comment: `AnyView` is highly discouraged dont use it `any View` doesn't work (existensials are very limited with SwiftUI) you need `some View` or any value that is`View`. Views shouldn't be held in variables unless they are in `@ViewBuilder`

Comment: existential types don't conform to themselves. So using `any URLEncodableView` is not possible. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself

Comment: @loremipsum Thank you for the comment. Can you elaborate please? I am not trying to store `View`s - but `View.self`-Types. The idea is to avoid a chain of `if (ExampleView.canDecode(data) { ExampleView(from: data) } else if (OtherExampleView.canDecode(data) { OtherExampleView(from: data) } else if { // ... }` and so on. I know that this chain of `if/else` would work in a `@ViewBuilder`...but I hoped I could avoid it.

Comment: The View shouldn't be deciding what view should be shown the data should.  Views  shouldnt do "work" there are just presenting data and transmitting user actions. I cant give you an alternative without a real example, how is MyData different?

Comment: @loremipsum I understand. But somehow *a View* needs to decide, since `navigationDestination(for:)` is a function on View. It's basically *the* routing function in SwiftUI, at least as far as I can tell. How would you structure/resolve this issue of constructing the *right* `View` for the data?

Comment: MyData decides not the View, based on MyData you present something. if MyData is a Image use one view if My data is a JSON use another View

Comment: @loremipsum So you suggest to put knowledge about the `View`s into `MyData`? E.g. `MyData.view(for data:MyData) -> some View`? That would be moving the problem, but would lead to the same type/syntax/mechanics problems, right?

Comment: not `MyData`, `myData` you should use `self` not `Self`

Comment: @loremipsum Unfortunately I have trouble understanding what you're suggesting. Can you please elaborate, maybe with an example?

Comment: I need an example from you first, How is `MyData` different I need a real example.

Comment: @loremipsum `MyData` is a type that could be anything. E.g. a `URL`. So, I'm e.g. looking for the `View` that can be initialized from a given `URL`. But not every `View` can open every `URL`. The `View` checks whether the URL applieas to itself (has the right path, query params, etc.) to initialize itself from. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One Solution but not ideal because while checking the `suffix` is fast you wouldn't want to check every time the view is redrawn.

```
extension URL {
    @ViewBuilder var view : some View {
        if self.lastPathComponent.hasSuffix("mp4") {
            Text("shoe video player")
        } else if self.lastPathComponent.hasSuffix("png") {
            AsyncImage(url: self)
        } else {
            Text("unsupported")
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use it something like

```
url.view
```

but like I mentioned above the decision will be happening multiple times, views shouldn't be deciding.

You could decide before and then tell the `View` what it is and what to show.

```
enum URLTypes: Hashable, Codable {
    case mp4(URL)
    case png(URL)
    ///Creates a type
    static func decode(url: URL) -> Self {
        if url.lastPathComponent.hasSuffix("mp4") {
            return .mp4(url)
        } else if url.lastPathComponent.hasSuffix("png") {
            return.png(url)
        } else {
            return .unknown(url)
        }
    }
    //What to show
    @ViewBuilder var view: some View {
        switch self {
        case .mp4(let uRL):
            Text("show video player \(uRL)")
        case .png(let uRL):
            AsyncImage(url: uRL)
        case .unknown(let uRL):
            Text("unsupported \(uRL)")
        }
    }
}
```

And use it in your `navigationDestination`

```
.navigationDestination(for: URLTypes.self) { data in
     data.view
}
```

But you could use generics too just be concrete when you get to the `View`

```
struct MyData<Content>: Hashable, Codable where Content: Hashable & Codable {
    
    let value: Content
    
    init(double: Double) where Content == Double {
        value = double
    }
    
    init(string: String) where Content == String {
        value = string
    }
    init(int: Int) where Content == Int {
        value = int
    }
    init(url: URL) where Content == URLTypes {
        value = URLTypes.decode(url: url)
    }
}
```

And in the `navigationDestination`

```
.navigationDestination(for: MyData<URLTypes>.self) { data in
    data.value.view
}
.navigationDestination(for: MyData<Double>.self) { data in
    Text(data.value, format: .number.precision(.fractionLength(2)))
}
```

The more decisions and processing your put on a `View`/main thread/ main actor the slower and more sluggish your app will be.

Comment: I like the approach and see how moving the decision out of the `View` into the model/controller is preferable. Apart from potential performance benefits, it shifts the solution to a space outside `any/some/Any/View` territory. It's basically inverting the question, from asking the `View`: "Can you open this Data?" to asking the Data: "What is your preferred view?". This answer helps solving my issue, but it won't help people finding this thread looking for a way to iterate protocolled views - guess the answer to that is: you shouldn't.

Comment: @Haensl that is a good way to put it. SwiftUI should be transactional, I have x show y. As short and as simple as possible. The other approach just doesn’t work because SwiftUI wants to know exactly what it has, the more detail the better any and Any hide the details.